# como pasar valor de una variable de .cs a una variable de javascript?

Tags: c#

tengo una variable en .css  tipo string

```
string RespGeneralimg = " | " +ImgResp1 + " | "  + ImgResp2 + "|" + ImgResp3 + "|" + ImgResp4 + "|" + ImgResp5 + "|" + ImgResp6 + "|" + ImgResp7 + "|" + ImgResp8 + "|" + ImgResp9 + "|" + ImgResp10 + "|" + ImgResp11;
```

pero esta cadena quiero mandar el valor a una variable de javascript para despues con un procedimiento separar esta cadena en javascript

Comment: Por un lado, creo que te refieres a .cs (código c#) y por el otro lado tienes que dar más detalles. Si quieres usar JavaScript imagino que sería en asp.net mvc o webforms o otros?

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando mvc puedes utilizar el ViewBag y ponerlo en un input type hidden y con javascript recoges el valor y lo almacenas en una variable de javascript